# project-to-test pom configuration doesn't seem to take effect

Tags: java, maven-plugin

I'm new to Java scene and was attempting to create a maven plugin.

I started with the archetype 'maven-archetype-plugin' and it comes with a default testing scaffold with artifact id 'maven-plugin-testing-harness'.

One confusing thing I've observed is that in the pom of testing directory 'project-to-test' exists a configuration over output directory

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>my-plugin-artifact-id</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <!-- Specify the MyMojo parameter -->
          <outputDirectory>target/test-harness/project-to-test</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

This parameter configuration didn't seem to take effect at all. The actually output path was set to default ('./target/) regardless

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After running maven commands in the project-to-test directory, I've realized that the newly created plugin was resolved to package org.apache, which is completely wrong.

With this hint I've added  label to the pom build section and it now behave as expected.